# oneM2M: can an announced resource have a non announced resource as it's child

Tags: m2m, onem2m

In oneM2M, can an announced resource have a non announced resource as it's child? I went through the documentations for oneM2M but can't find anywhere that clearly mentions this.

For example, on my IN-CSE, I have created an announced AE (AE_ANNC), then I create an announced Container (CNT_ANNC), now can I have a normal Content Instance (non announced resource) inside this new announced container ie, inside CNT_ANNC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "I have created an announced AE (AE_ANNC)" do you mean you (or one of your AEs) created the resource directly, or that it was created by the hosting CSE (ie announced) when you set the "at" attribute of the original AE?

Comment: Hi @AndreasKraft, It was created by hosting CSE when I set "at" attribute of the original AE. Basically, I want to announce all the resources (AE, CNT, CIN) to IN-CSE, so I believe, I will have to create Announced Content Instance inside CNT_ANNC. Regular Content Instance inside CNT_ANNC can be created by IN-CSE or its AEs only, so its better to create Announced Content Instance only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In oneM2M you can put a regular resource as a child of an announced resource. Specifically, the example that you provide is allowed.

There is not a lot of detail on this, but for each resource the table of child resources has a column to the right that indicates valid child resources of the announced variant of the resource. For your example,TS-0001 table 9.6.6-1 shows that a <containerAnnc> can have both <contentInstance> and <contentInstanceAnnc> child resources.